# Should I leave the variable as transient?

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark, transient

I have been experimenting with Apache Spark trying to solve some queries like top-k, skyline etc.

I have made a wrapper which encloses `SparkConf` and `JavaSparkContext` named `SparkContext`. This class also implements serializable but since `SparkConf` and `JavaSparkContext` are not serializable then the class isn't either.

I have a class solving the topK query named `TopK`, the class implements serializable but the class also has a `SparkContext` member variable which is not serializable (for the reason above). Therefore I am getting an exception whenever I try to execute a `TopK` method from within a `.reduce()` function in an RDD.

The solution I have found is to make `SparkContext` transient.

My question is: Should I keep the `SparkContext` variable as transient or am I doing a big mistake?

**`SparkContext` class:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;

public class SparkContext implements Serializable {

    private final SparkConf sparConf; // this is not serializable
    private final JavaSparkContext sparkContext; // this is not either

    protected SparkContext(String appName, String master) {
        this.sparConf = new SparkConf();
        this.sparConf.setAppName(appName);
        this.sparConf.setMaster(master);

        this.sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparConf);
    }

    protected JavaRDD<String> textFile(String path) {
        return sparkContext.textFile(path);
    }

}
```

**`TopK` class:**

```
public class TopK implements QueryCalculator, Serializable {

    private final transient SparkContext sparkContext;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

**Example that throws `Task not serializable` exception.** `getBiggestPointByXDimension` won't even get entered because in order for it to be executed in a reduce function the class enclosing it (`TopK`) must be serializable.

```
private Point findMedianPoint(JavaRDD<Point> points) {
    Point biggestPointByXDimension = points.reduce((a, b) -> getBiggestPointByXDimension(a, b));
    .
    .
    .
}

private Point getBiggestPointByXDimension(Point first, Point second) {
        return first.getX() > second.getX() ? first : second;
    }
```

Comment: Why does TopK need to be Serializable at all?

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer I added an example in the post. The problem pretty much is that I can't execute a function inside a `reduce()` function unless the class that the function originates from is Serializable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To your question: *Should I keep the SparkContext variable as transient*?

Yes. That's ok. It's only encapsulating the (Java)SparkContext and the context is not usable on the workers, so marking it `transient` just tells the Serializer not to serialize that field.

You could also have your own `SparkContext` wrapper not serializable and mark it as transient - same effect as above. (BTW, Given that SparkContext is the Scala class name for the spark context, I'd chose another name to avoid confusion down the road.)

One more thing: As you pointed out, the reason why Spark is trying to serialize the complete enclosing class, is because a method of the class is being used within a closure. Avoid that!.  Use an anonymous class or a self-contained closure (which will translate into an anonymous class at the end).

Comment: So you are saying I should have a separate class (like `TopKProcessor`) that is going to encapsulate every action that I would want to take on an RDD (like `reduce()`, `reduceByKey()` etc.)?

Comment: no, I'm saying that instead of doing defining methods for each operation like `points.reduce((a, b) -> getBiggestPointByXDimension(a, b))` you could just declare those simple operations within the closure like: `points.reduce((a, b) -> a.getX() > b.getX() ? a: b)` to avoid calling methods defined on a class.

Comment: I agree with you for that occassion I could probably do it like that but there are other occassions that the computation logic is too big and it would get a nested mess. But I will do my best to avoid that.

Comment: or learn you some Scala - Scala and Spark make a great combination.

Comment: I have seen how Scala was used in Spark and I found it quite easy and possibly better than Java (for tasks like these) but I am collaborating with a professor of mine on this and we agreed on using Java. In the future though I am pretty sure I will study some Scala since I liked it.

Comment: @DimitrisK: Spark supports Java 8 lambda expressions, which makes it a lot easier to read. If an action's code becomes too long, moving it to a separate class might be a good idea.